# How to combine multiple monad effects into the same do block?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a function that calls functions of type `IO` and functions of type `Either String a`.

I would like to combine the effects in the do notation, so that I can unpack `IO` when necessary and at the same time abort the computation at the first `Left` I encounter.

Here is a very simple example, can you help me fix it? (use of runEitherT is optional. But I think if you use plain either you won't be able to use `MonadError` and `MonadIO` features).

```
entryPoint :: IO (Either String Int)
entryPoint = runEitherT foo

-- p and p' should have type Int,
-- and errorf can force the computation to abort (as can throwError) 
foo :: EitherT String IO Int
foo = do
  p <- liftIO $ iof 1
  p' <- return $ errorf p
  if p' == 2
    then throwError "No!"
    else return 1

errorf :: b -> Either String b
errorf = undefined

iof :: a -> IO a
iof = undefined
```

Comment: `p' <- return $ errorf p` looks weird. You may be looking for `p' <- EitherT $ return $ errorf p`. Also, `throwError` may be `left` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `EitherT` and then throwing `undefined` about. That seems pretty weird. What are you actually trying to accomplish? The names `entryPoint` and `foo` are not so descriptive.

Comment: because the implementation doesn't matter, as long as you know that one method does IO and another one uses Either to report errors. I'm pretty sure `EitherT String IO Int` is the correct type for the behavior I need so I just need the code to typecheck

Comment: @chi It compiles, thanks. So basically `return $ errorf p'` already had the correct type in an abstract sense, but I had to pack it further into an `EitherT` to satisfy the typechecker?

Comment: Almost. The original `return $ x` is in `EitherT s IO` and means success, modeled as `EitherT (return (Right x))` where the latter `return` produces `IO`. So, the original code builds `EtiherT (return (Right (Left ...)))` since `x=Left ..` which is wrong. Instead using `EitherT $ return $ errorf p` we use the `return` to produce `IO` (not `EitherT ...`), so we get `EitherT (return (Left ...))`. It's weird because it _appears_ that we are packing it further, when we are not: adding `EitherT` makes Haskell to choose a different `return` (in `IO` instead of `EitherT`) !

Comment: @chi For this question, your observation and explanations are good enough to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part

```
p' <- return $ errorf p
```

looks wrong. Here, `return` builds a monadic value in `EitherT String IO`. Assuming that `errorf p = Left something` the value which is being built is

```
p' <- EitherT (return (Right (Left something)))
```

where the above `return` builds an `IO` action. This is not what we want -- there is an extra `Right` there. We instead want

```
p' <- EitherT (return (Left something))
```

which is

```
p' <- EitherT $ return $ errorf p
```

Comment: Why should throwError from Control.Monad.Error.Class be changed to left? It compiles with throwError, and i feel like the name captures the semantics better.

Comment: @BruceBerry I was wrong about `throwError` -- I thought that one was raising an exception in `IO`, which is not the case.